# Why is a measure word not required in 一年有三百六十五天?

Tags: measure-word

Consider the following two sentences:

> A year has twelve months
> 一年有十二個月
> <sub>yī nián yǒu shí’èr gè yuè</sub>
>
> A year has three hundred and sixty-five days
> 一年有三百六十五天
> <sub>yī nián yǒu sānbǎi liùshíwǔ tiān</sub>

Why is the measureword 個 left out in the second sentence? What is the general grammar rule for cases like this?

Comment: 一年有十二月 Would mean "One year has December in it"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some nouns need a classifier, some don't; 月(month) needs one but 天(day) doesn't.

一年有十二個月 - 月(month) needs a classifier

一年有十二個月份 - 月份(month) needs a classifier

一年有五十二週 - 週(week) doesn't need a classifier

一年有五十二個星期 - 星期(week) needs a classifier

一年有三百六十五天 - 天(day) doesn't need a classifier

一年有四季 - 季(season) doesn't need a classifier

一年有四個季節 - 季節 (season) needs a classifier

一小時有六十分鐘 - 分鐘(minute) doesn't need a classifier

一分鐘有六十秒 - 秒(second) doesn't need a classifier

Generally, if a noun can be a classifier itself, it usually doesn't need a classifier. 週, 天, 季,  分鐘 and 秒 can all be classifier

Example: 三週工資, 兩天比賽, 一季收成, 幾分鐘路程, 幾秒時間

Answer (score 0):

A year has twelve months, 一年有十二**個**月。

A year has three hundred and sixty-five days, 一年有三百六十五天。

The question is when to use the measure word **個**, but when to not use it?

It depends on a couple of factors.

We say 一年有十二**個**月 but **not** say 一年有**十二月**. It is because 十二月 is the twelfth month of the year (December). That is why you have to say 十二**個**月 to avoid confusion.

You can say 二月有**二十八天**。No need to say 二月有二十八個天。The 28th day of the month is **二十八号**。

Another example of using 個, 这个月有二十一**個**工作日。

Also, 邓丽君演唱的《你怎么说》，“**三百六十五個日子**不好过，你心里根本没有我”.

Answer (score 0):

三月 -> March

三个月 -> Three months

The usage without "个" is occupied by special meanings (a time point) so the "个" is added to express a period of time.